# Routing traffic coming from specific IP to go through specific gateway

Tags: nic, route

This is my problem. I have a server with 2 nic cards A and B

A (10.x.x.1)  Default Gateway (10.x.x.254)
B (192.x.x.1) Default Gateway (empty)

NIC A all outbound traffic goes out through it.
NIC B connected to separate router 192.x.x.254

On that router we have NAT set-up to allow RDP forwarding port 3389 to 192.x.x.1 (NIC B). I am trying to RDP by accessing (externally) 192.x.x.254 but it times out.

Is there a static route I could add to make RDP possible? (This is on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Looks like the return traffic is not taking the right path. If you will always come from the same subnet you could create a static route for that subnet pointing traffic to 192.x.x.254.

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a static route I could add to make RDP possible?`

Only if you're connecting from a known external ip address. All other traffic will be routed through the default gateway. If you connect from a known external ip address then you could add a static route for that ip address to the 192.x.x.1 interface.